# Excel formula for specific use

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I want to write somthing in cell A1 and it should get replace with A1*100 automatically. Can we do this?

e.g. If i type 23 in Cell C2, then this value should get replace with (C2*100)

Comment: Yes. For replacing the actual content you need `VBA` though. For replacing the layout you can use the format options ("#\0\0").

Comment: Is it A1 you want this formula on or is it C2, or is it the whole sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213612). It gives a good outline of how to trigger a macro when an event happens, like changing the value of certain cells. There is also [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx), from Microsoft that explains `Worksheet.Change(Target)`.